# Meteor.js findOne() cannot find by _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, find

I am trying to find a document in my collection using .findOne(), and searching by _id.

```
pinnedForumTopics.findOne({_id : 0})
```

(I know that I have a document in my collection with that id)  but this still doesn't return anything.  Anybody know whats up?  (I can search by other things, just not _id...)

here is where I define my collection:

```
pinnedForumTopics = new Mongo.Collection("pinnedForumTopics");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

**EDIT**
I am using autopublish***

Comment: Are you sure _id : 0 is an integer and not a string?

Comment: @stivaugoin I've tried both 0 and "0", unfortunately nether work

Comment: in console if you run  pinnedForumTopics.find().fetch() do you see a document with _id = 0? Typically, auto-generated ids in meteor is a random string.

Comment: Are you using the *autopublish* package and if not did you both *publish* (from the server) and *subscribe* (from the client) to your *pinnedForumTopics* collection?

Comment: I am using autopublish, sorry for the confusion.  I'll update the question now with that information.

Comment: Have you run `pinnedForumTopics.find().fetch()` in your console and see a document with _id = 0? Or you can also download a **robo mongo**, a GUI MongoDB manager, connect it with your meteor mongo collection(localhost:3001) to see what inside your collection

Answer (score 3):

I think there may be something wrong in your code, because your query is right.

You should first check whether there are anything whose _id is 0, what's the result of running `pinnedForumTopics.find().fetch()` in your console?

Have you remove the `auto-publish` in your meteor app? If so, you should publish and subscribe data by yourself, then you could get the data you want.

If not, I suggest that you could download robomongo, a GUI mongoDB manager, in which you could easily debug with. Like this:

[image]